# Cannot create bitmap after round number

Tags: powershell, bitmap

I cannot succeed to create a bitmap in powershell after use round function. Can someone help me please ?

```
$newWidth = [Math]::Round($idealWidth * $ratioOriginal);
$bmpResized = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($newWidth, 800)
```

I get : `Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Parameter is not valid."`

This will work `New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap(800, 800)` but I need to calculate a new width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `[Math]::round` gives you a number of type `double`.
`System.Drawing.Bitmap` on the other hand needs two numbers of type `int` as arguments.
By casting your `$newWidth` var to an int you can get your code working.